# censor word from text file and create new file

Tags: python, function, file

using python to censor the word "winter" from user input file - "y.txt"
wrote some code but i'm running into errors. any occurrence of the word "winter" should be gone. help and thanks!

```
filename = input("Enter file name (without extension): ")
file1 = filename+".txt"
file2 = filename+"_censored.txt"

word = input("Enter the word you are searching for: ")
#In this case, the input would be "winter"

print("\nLooping through the file, line by line.")

in_text_file = open(file1, "r")

out_text_file = open(file2,"w")

for line in in_text_file:
    print(line)
out_text_file.write(line)

n = [ ]

def censor(word, filename):
   for i in text.split(""):
        if i == word:
            i = "*" * len(word)
            n.append(i)
        else:
            n.append(i)
            return "".join(n)

censor(word,filename)

in_text_file.close()
out_text_file.close()
```

im getting the errors
[image]

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @dartdog just edited the question!

Comment: You never define 'text' and assign something to it

Answer (score 0):

the word winter is not quoted: censor(winter,filename) should be censor("winter",filename) or censor(word, filename)

Edit: also you need to open the file and read a line into the text variable.

Personally, I would use regular expressions to avoid gotchas with periods.

```
import re
```

then for each line:

```
line = re.sub(r'(^| )word here($| |\.|,|\;)','*****',line);
```